# Get oreder/sequence of columns from the list

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I am trying to get the sequence/order of columns from sharepoint list. How can I do that?

```
        List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("List1");
        ctx.Load(list);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such thing as column order in SharePoint list. Columns are ordered in content types and views.

Of course you can load `list.Fields` collection and enumerate over them but this is not real order.

Get [ContentType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.contenttype.aspx) fields order:

```
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("List1");
ctx.Load(list);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
if (list.ContentTypesEnabled) {
    ctx.Load(list.ContentTypes);
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    ContentType ct = list.ContentTypes[0];

    // ct.FieldLinks will give column order in content type
}
```

Get [View](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.view.aspx) fields order:

```
List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("List1");
ctx.Load(list);
ctx.Load(list.DefaultView)
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

// list.DefaultView.ViewFields will give column order in view
```